# Is there a way of editing an existing calendar instance in Kotlin?

Tags: android, date, kotlin, calendar

I have very little experience with Kotlin, so please do let me know if my approach is needlessly convoluted.

I have a variable *curDate* that is defined as *Calendar.getInstance().time* and I wish to create another variable that is identical to the original one, but with some values like the year, month etc. changed.

If I were to define *newDate* as *Calendar.getInstance()* I could obviously use *newDate.set*, but when dealing with *curDate.clone()* this is not an option.

Is there a way to change existing calendar instances and what would be the most optimal solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used Kotlin. But Calendar is the same, only syntax changes.

Try this:

```
  Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance()
  Calendar cal2 = (Calendar)cal1.clone()

  cal2.set(int field, int value)
```

Hope to have helped you! :-) Let me know if I understood well your achieve

Comment: This is what I got: you wanna get two instance equal, the second one with a different field (year or month or ecc...)

Comment: Thank you very much! I had misunderstood how kotlin.time should be used and Calendar.getInstance() did the trick.

Comment: That's the beginning! Have a nice learning!